# Android Combined Date-Time Picker

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I need to integrate one dialog in my app which asks for Date and Time in single dialog.
Problem is that, natively Android supports this individually, So please suggest me any such library if you know.

[image: I need this kind of functionality]

Comment: Hello, why don't you create a custom dialog view? You can integrate the default datePicker in it.

Comment: Check this- https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker

Comment: @ArnaudPradier I need this in single dialog, which is not possible using DatePicker and TimePicker because it requires two screens

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. There are plenty of catalogs of Android libraries, such as the Android Arsenal, that you can examine to see if you can find something that meets your needs.

Comment: found one: [library](https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker)

Comment: Check this - https://github.com/niyaz434/DateTimePickerLibraryDemo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found one such library. 
Please check here:
https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker